# Red thing inside of capsule object that shows when running the game in Unity

Tags: unity

There is a red thing inside of my capsule object that shows when running the game in Unity. How do I make it invisible? I have tried looking at the capsule collider, but I couldn't find anything to make it invisible. Please take a look at the screenshots added to this question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like you just hit the Gismos toogle.

Comment: To clarify ... Top-right hand corner of the play window is a "Gizmos" drop-down which lets you pick which gizmos are visible. Should only apply to running in the editor, not final builds.

Comment: @Zibelas That seems to be it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Basic Thanks, that solved it indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gizmo drawn by one of the scripts you have running in this scene. Look for functions called `OnDrawGizmos` or `OnDrawGizmosSelected`. They'll be calling `Gizmos.DrawWireSphere` to draw this item, so you can comment out that line if you never want to see this.

You can also click the "Gizmos" button in the top bar of your Game tab to turn off drawing of gizmos in the game view.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, that solved it.